# What does "from 1% all the way up to 100%" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idioms

I have question regarding the meaning of "from 1% all the way up to 100%". This sentence might not be formal or grammatically correct, but i heard people using it quite often.

Does it mean from 1% to 100% without stop? Or it can mean gradually change, like from 1%->10%->50%->100%.

In our case, we have a software system. We usually open up this system to users starting from 1% of the user base, if no issue reported by users, open it up to 10% and then 50%, and finally 100% of all the users. (This is to ensure if there is issue with the system, only limited amount of users affected.) When some people saying "from 1% all the way up to 100%", sometime other people are confused. Some take it as 1% -> 100% directly. Others take it as 1% -> 10% -> 50% ->100% gradually.

Comment: Can you give a full example please, or better yet a few examples? Context may well modify the meaning here.

Comment: I can think of several possible meanings.  Examples would help.

Comment: In different contexts, the form *"from x to y"* can mean a variety of things. For example, the expression "from 0 to 60" usually means continuously from 0 to 60 because it refers to a car's acceleration. But if I say, "I'm thinking of a number from 0 to 60", it's clearly not a continuous thing because it's just one number, and it's implied that it's an integer value, not any of the numbers in between

Comment: Thanks all for your kindly help. A little bit context here. In our case, we have a software system. We usually open up this system to users starting from 1% of the user base, if no issue reported by users, open it up to 10% and then 50%, and finally 100% of all the users. (This is to ensure if there is issue with the system, only limited amount of users affected.) When some people saying "from 1% all the way up to 100%",  sometime other people are confused. Some take it as 1% -> 100% directly. Others take it as 1% -> 10% -> 50% ->100% gradually. Thanks everyone.

Comment: It's best to edit this information into the question itself. I've done it for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

"*Starting from* 1% of the user base" means that is their *starting point*. They begin the software roll-out process by sending it to 1% of their user base.

They outline various steps in between, but their final step is to send it out to 100% of their user base (everybody). "*All the way up to...*" means that is their *end point*.

If you think about a physical journey, we speak about going *from* one place, *to* another. We can describe a process the same way - the first step of a process is where we begin *from*. They could just have easily said "starting *with* 1% of the user base" which would be equally correct but a different way of describing it.